# unhandled js exception: application main has not been registered expo TestFlight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight, unhandled-exception

> I have a ios app develop by react native expo. now that's on the
>   testing environment.I already installed working successfully some
>   iPhone without any issue.
>
> But my iphone x i installed the app without any error then i click the
>   app end up this blow error what is the reason[image]

Comment: Erase the app on your iPhone, power it off, run it again, and install the app.

Comment: @hongdevelop i tried no use

Comment: Why not use?????

Comment: @hongdevelop , I tried user suggestion but not work

Comment: or you can change registerComponent name. `AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => Root);`

Comment: @hongdevelop .  expo framework doesn't have index.js

Comment: `index.js` of expo is `App.js`

Comment: App.js doesn’t have that code @hongdevelop

Comment: apply link https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1323#issuecomment-407692650

Comment: You create the new issue or contribute to that issue, there are limited, I can't put anything on that  @hongdevelop

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with expo both on Testflight and production APP as well. It happens when the app is killed and re-open.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue with my application in production (Apple Store), but it doesn't happen on every build. I use ejected Expo.